# How to get the order of a group generator in DH?

Tags: diffie-hellman, prime-numbers, group-theory, safe-prime

For a DH parameter prime, if the generator $g$ is 2, how do I get the order $q$?

Comment: This question is wrong. The group order is part of the group specification in DHKE. There’s no concept of “getting group order from the generator”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generator $g$ means that $g$ generates the group $\langle g \rangle =G$. Therefore the order of the group $ord(G)$ is equal to the order of the generator $ord(g)$.

If $2$ ( or any other element) is not a generator that is $\langle 2 \rangle \neq G$  then the element $2$ forms a subgroup under the group operation. Then the order of $2$ must divide the order of the group, $ord(2) | ord(G)$ by [the Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory));

> if $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$, then the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$

Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange can be used with multiplicative and additive groups. DHKE represents the multiplicative version and ECDH is the additive version with the Elliptic Curves over a finite field $E(K)$.

For the multiplicative group To find the order, factor the $ord(G)$ then find the smallest factor $x$ , $x|ord(G)$, such that $g^x = 1$, where $g^x$ means $$g^x = \underbrace{a \cdot a \cdot a \cdots a}_{x\text{ times}}.$$

In the additive group like ECC, you need to check that $[x]G = \mathcal{O}$ where $\mathcal{O}$ is the identity element of the curve,   $G$ is a base element and $[x]G$ means $$[x]G = \underbrace{a + a + a + a}_{x\text{ times}}.$$

Both can be checked efficiently,

- for the multiplicative group;  [square-and-multiply algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)
- and for the ECC; [double-and-add algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Double-and-add).

In the DHKE, in practice, we chose a [safe prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime) $p = 2 q +1$ where $q$ is another prime and called [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime). In this case, the order of $G$ is only divisible by 2 and $q$, then we can choose the $g$ as the generator of the subgroup $H$ of order $q$. Since $q$ is a prime, then any element of $H$ is a generator. Take a random, or find the smallest element $x$, such that $g^2 \neq 1$ and $g^q =1 $ then we have a generator.

In the safe prime case, we have 4 possible groups orders $\{1,2,q,2q\}$ and the groups are $\{1\},\{1,-1\}$, the quadratic residues, and the whole group. In this case, to find a generator with order $q$ quadratic residues is enough, and quadratic non-residues will have $2q$ order, other than the $\{1,-1\}$. To pick a generator, the law of quadratic residues can be used. The results are in [Poncho's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87142/18298);

The theory behind this is the [Second Supplement to Law of Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#q_=_%C2%B12_and_the_second_supplement);
\begin{align}\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = (-1)^{(p^2-1)/8} \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
and there is an [elemtary proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/180022/338051) of the above statement and $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)$ is the multiplicative [Legendry Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

- $2$ is a square modulo $p$ if and only if $p\equiv\pm 1\mod 8$ and thus the order is $q$.
- $2$ is not a square modulo $p$ if and only if $p\equiv\pm 3\mod 8$ and thus the order is $2q$.

If you are looking for some examples see [RFC 2412, Appendix E ‘The Well-Known Groups’](http://RFC%202412,%20Appendix%20E%20%E2%80%98The%20Well-Known%20Groups%E2%80%99.)).

In the case of ECDH, the process a bit more complex, We don't need to choose curves with a prime number of rational points like NIST P-224 where every element is a generator, however, it doesn't have twist security and side-channel free Montgomery ladder.

Answer (score 3):

To extend kelalaka's answer, if $p$ is a safe prime (that is, if $p = 2q+1$ with $q$ prime), then:

- If $p \equiv 7 \pmod 8$, then the order of $g=2$ will be $q$
- If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 8$, then the order of $g=2$ will be $2q$
- If $p = 5$ (the only other possibility), then the order of $g=2$ is 4 (that is, $2q$)

Comment: Nice extension, thanks,